# Why aren't these two areas the same?

Tags: calculus

If the area of

$$\int_0^{\ln4}4-e^x \;dx=2.545$$

Then if we find the same equation in terms of $y$ it will be

$$\int_1^4\ln(y)\;dy$$

If we were to rotate this function around the $y$ axis by $360^\circ$ we get $8.158$ but when we rotate it in terms of $x$ (first equation) around the $x$ axis it is $17.846$

Shouldnt both areas be the same, if not why?

Comment: Solving for x yields $\ln{(4-y)}$ not the equation you've written

Comment: The question really seems to be 'why aren't the two *volumes* the same'?

Answer (score 0):

If you rotate an area around the $x$ axis to get volume $V_x$ and rotate the same area around the $y$ axis to get volume $V_y$, there is no reason why $V_x$ and $V_y$ should be equal.

Consider a simpler example of the rectangle in $xy$ plane with corners at $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$, $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$. Rotating about either axis creates a cylinder and the volume of a cylinder with radius $r$ and height $h$ is $\pi r^2 h$. For the rectangle this leads to $V_x = 2 \pi$  and $V_y = 4 \pi$ i.e. $V_x \ne V_y$.